# What (self.nsmutablearray)[indexPath.row] means?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm developing a contact list for studying purposes and this question came while studying.

**Here's the problem:** I'm configuring a cell for my TableView and one of my friends said that I should use (self.nsmutablearray)[indexPath.row], however I don't understand why I should use (self.nsmutablearray) before [indexPath.row]. I know it's a dumb question, but I just can't understand how exactly the programming paradigm works.
**Here's the code** (Contact is a NSObject and contactList is a NSMutablArray):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ContactCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    Contact *contact = (self.contactList)[indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = contato.name;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: the [] syntax is just shorthand for [self.contactList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]

Comment: @Paulw11 actually, it stands for `objectAtIndexedSubscript:`.

Comment: The parentheses aren't needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's index subscripting.

`self.contactList` represents an array of `Contact` objects.  You need to fetch a contact at a certain row in the table so you can populate the cell with data.  `indexPath` represents a section and row in a table, and `indexPath.row` represents just the row.  Therefore, you can write `self.contactList[indexPath.row]` which retrieves the element at that index from the array.

Alternatively, you could write `[self.contactList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]`